# Installing Linux Mint on Windows-Ubuntu Dual Boot

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, windows, system-installation, dual-boot

I currently have an Ubuntu-Windows Dual boot. However, I would like to try out a new OS so I burned Linux Mint to a USB stick.

I would like to install Linux Mint and remove Ubuntu while still keeping my windows dual boot. I've already backed up my Ubuntu setup so I can wipe it out.

In the Linux Mint installer, should I choosing the "install alongside windows" option do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes assuming you've already taken care and backed up any files of consequence on your Ubuntu installation you can just select "install alongside windows" during the Linux Mint installation process.

The pre-existing Ubuntu partition can safely be ignored, just make sure you select the same partition that it was installed to for Linux Mint.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. What if I want to increase my linux partition? Can I do this from the installer?

Comment: Yes, assuming there is unused space to make use of on the HDD. In general you should be able to delete the pre-existing partitions that the previous installation was using and recreate them. I'd let the installer dictate what it wants, and just delete these pre-existing partitions.